# How to get the combinations of fixed number of elements and variable number of used elements (no repetitions)

Tags: java

How to write a recursive method in Java which prints the combinations of 3 different numbers with variable count of the numbers used? (No repetitions should be included.) That is, the method should work for different combination lengths. For example, with the numbers 0, 1, 2 and two numbers used in the combinations you should have: 0  0 - 0  1 - 0  2 - 1  1 - 1  2 - 2  2.

With the same numbers, combinations of 3 numbers are: 
0  0  0 - 0  0  1 - 0  0  2 - 0  1  1 - 0  1  2 - (...),
and so on.
I have checked several types of recursion methods in other similar topics, but I still cannot thoroughly understand this and write my own method.

Comment: Open IDE.
Create JAVA project.
Create class.
Implement your method.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow.. Please read the guidelines for asking questions.. http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try calculating all permutations first. Then move on to calculating combinations. The images on the wiki are very enlightening https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

You could try pen and paper through this code as well: [Combinations method return issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22133117/combinations-method-return-issue)!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have seen the suggested solution, however, recursive methods seem harder to implement. If you are interested, see my solution. I don't know if it is okay in relation to execution speed etc., but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a non-recursive solution based on counting the numbers of an n-based numeral system. E.g., for system with base 3, numbers are added which are powers of 3.

It should be noted that this prints all combinations, and the ones with repetitive elements should be later removed, as is needed in my case. For example, from the combinations 001, 010, 100, only the first one should be left, where the elements are in ascending order.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int t = 2;
    int r = 2;
    ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int tmp;
    for (int p = 0; p <= (int)(Math.pow((double)t, (double)r)) - 1; p++) {
        tmp = p;
        for (int q = r - 1; q >= 0; q--) {
            for (int s = t - 1; s >= 0; s--) {
                if (tmp >= s * (int) (Math.pow(t, q))) {
                    l.add(Integer.valueOf(s));
                    tmp = tmp - s * (int) (Math.pow(t, q));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= l.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (i % r != r - 1) {
            System.out.print(l.get(i) + "-");
        } else {
            System.out.println(l.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```